# Should I pick N-Tier architecture over MVC?

Tags: .net, winforms, design-patterns, architecture

I have to develop a application (Winforms-application) which is connected to a database within a enterprise-intranet.

As I want to keep the application ascalable, maintainable & flexible I a m thinking on which architecture I should use.
In this connection I stumbeled over the N-Tier and MVC Patterns.

As far as I got it the main difference between the two patterns is that MVC has a more triangular structure (Components can communicate with each other), while 3-Tier applications have a straight structure where each component (n) can only forward requests to the component (n+1).

So my idea would be to take the 3-Tier approach. Where the **"Presentation Layer, Tier-1"** holds the Forms, the **"Business Layer, Tier-2"** handles the information and logic between Tier-1 and Tier-3 and the **"Data Layer, Tier-3"** is connected to the database and works with stored procedures.

**My question is:**

Does this sound like a reasonable desicion to you? Because I read that N-Tier makes sence if you plan on running the single Tiers on different machines, which I do not plan to do. 
If you think I chose the wrong approach, what would be a better idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mod, can you tell me how this question is not constructive?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC and n-tier are two architecture patterns at different levels covering different aspects. They can be used at the same time. It's not one or the other.

MVC is more a software architecture that can be applied in the presentation tier, one component being Windows Forms. (Whether Windows Forms is fully MVC compatible is a separate discussion.)

N-tier architecture is a system architecture (at a higher level than the MVC architecture). The decision is basically whether you have two tiers (the Windows Forms client as the first tier and the database with the stored procedures as the second tier) or three tiers (the Windows Forms client as the first tier, an application server with the business logic as the second tier, and the database with the third tier as the third tier). Or even shorter: Will the client directly connect to the database or is there an application server in between?

It seems that the use of stored procedures is given. If this is the case, then they probably provide more than just data querying and storage but some business logic as well. In such a case, I tend to go with two tiers.

Other factors that could be relevant are:

- Authentication: Is it possible to setup up all users in the database? Or would it be easier to do it on an application server and use a single user to acess the database? Is some sort of single sign on required?
- Authorization: Is is possible to check all rights and permissions in the database? If not, then three tiers are required to create a secure application?
- Are there any restrictions regarding the network architecture that prohibit to directly access the database?
- Do you expect several thousand concurrent users and would like to scale up by setting up several servers?

In general, I tend to go for fewer tiers since it's easier to implement and costs less (initially and during maintenance). The cost of additional tiers needs to be justified by requirements that depend on the extra tier.

Answer (score 4):

MVC and any other MVC related patterns such as MVP, MVVM are patterns that are assocated with the UI layer of an application. (be it Winforms/Web/WPF or what ever the UI framework is).

Basically these UI patterns promote loose coupling of the UI logic from the UI Presentation related aspects. 
They gives addvantages such as:

- Making UI Logic layer unit testable with automated unit test tools. (without having to spin up the actual UIs)
- Due to the loose coupling beween UI and UI logic components, UI logic classes become more re-usable. (i.e.Controllers and Models could be used by mutiple views)
- Also give additional benefits which wouldn't be used commonly such as being able to save the status of a UI by serializing the Models etc..

**MVC and N-Tiered architecture are not two opposite approaches from which you need to choose one or the other.** 
Depending on your requirenments, you can mix and match them to suite your application requirements.

For e.g. you can choose to have an overall 3-Tiered solution with UI, Business Logic and Data Access Layers. Within this you can choose to have your UI layer implemented in MVC style.

to clarifiy more, you can have your Business Logic layer as a set of services exposing business functionalities while communicating with the Data Access Layer for persistance.
At the same time Controllers on your UI layer could access these Business layer services for business functionalites and build Models/ViewModels to suite the Views.
Implementations could vastly differer, this is just an example.

**Basically these two patters can complement each other in offering a better solution.**